# debugging underscore.js templates is difficult without line numbers

Tags: underscore.js

I am converting a rather large php template (page with basic logic in it) into an underscore.js template.

The problem is that I keep having errors in it, and it's minified "compiled" version doesn't give useful information or line numbers when an error is thrown.

Is there a way to get better template debugging in underscore.js (such as line numbers)? And if not, is there a way to get the template to terminate at a point (this way I can narrow down where the error is).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Errata as of Apr 2012:** *Underscore 1.3.2 (April 9, 2012) have introduced changes to `_.template()`, check the [changelog](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog) and the source since complications to what have been described here might have shown up.*

Yes and no - the template is first translated to a string of (hard to read) Javascript code and the executed as one block of code, so if you're looking for a syntax error you must remove the offending code from the template you're trying to execute.

But if it's something else, embedding a `<% return __p.join(''); %>` will break execution and return the result of the template up to that point (read the source to see why, but essentially, the results of template blocks are put into an array named `__p` one after another).

You can also do logging while your template evaluates (i.e. put `<% console.log(<..>) %>` in your template to see diagnostics. For more advanced troubleshooting, you could also put a `<% debugger; %>` in your template code to drop into your favourite debugger. Although the code you'll see will be unfriendly to read you will have access to the evaluating templates scope.

If I were doing extensive work and needed more extensive debugging facilities, I'd probably take a copy of the `underscore.js` script and add some diagnostic support code to  the `_.template()` function itself. For example:

```js
_.template = function(str, data) {
  var c  = _.templateSettings;
  var tmpl = 'var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.apply(__p,arguments);};' +
    'with(obj||{}){__p.push(\'' +
    str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
       .replace(/'/g, "\\'")
       .replace(c.interpolate, function(match, code) {
         return "'," + code.replace(/\\'/g, "'") + ",'";
       })
       .replace(c.evaluate || null, function(match, code) {
         return "');" + code.replace(/\\'/g, "'")
                            .replace(/[\r\n\t]/g, ' ') + "__p.push('";
       })
       .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')
       .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
       .replace(/\t/g, '\\t')
       + "');}return __p.join('');";
  console.log(tmpl.replace(/;/g, '\n')); // <- dump compiled code to console before evaluating
  var func = new Function('obj', tmpl);
  return data ? func(data) : func;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you covered some good approaches and they will definately help in debugging. <br> It would be cool if there was a slower to process but easier to debug mode that the template could be run through. It would be worth it to be able to get the ability to have the same type of errors I see in php.<br>
I guess to do it, it would have to count the lines that between code blocks, and than keep some type of internal incrementer.

Answer (score 3):

In Backbone Eye (Firebug extension), you can debug underscore templates - just as if they were regular JavaScript files. The template id (if specified) comes up in the script window (of Firefox) and you can select it (just like a regular script file), put breakpoints and watch the template being incrementally built. More details on how to do this is at http://dhruvaray.github.io/spa-eye/#views. This should help you narrow down the source of your error easily.

[Disclaimer : I am the author of Backbone Eye]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a javascript syntax error inside a long template sometimes it can be hard to find, since the linter will not understand javascript inside <%%>

Use your editor replace function and replace:

Find:

```
%>[\s\S]*?<%[=-]?
```

Replace:

```
\n//html\n
```

It will remove any HTML between your javascript then you can use a linter or http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html to find for syntax errors.

[image: HTML template]

After replace all and beautified:
[image: remaining javascript]

Note: This regular expression will leave remaining HTML on the start and end of your file, so just remove those manually.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Internet Explorer Development tools console(F12). It is able to debug into your underscore template. I used chrome and firefox and the most I got was the line in jquery.js or underscore.js that the error occured. But the Internet explorer debugger went directly to the offending code inside the underscore template. This will enable you to figure out the error.